# Python 3: How does asyncio compare to GLib (from PyGObject)?

Tags: python-3.x, pygobject

How does `asyncio` compare to `Glib` from the `PyGObject` package in terms of performance and stability when being used for the main loop, timers, and asynchronous I/O?

I am wondering whether it is a good idea to move from using `GLib` to `asyncio` so that I could drop the extra dependency on `PyGObject`.

Examples of functions and classes I use from `gi.repository.GLib`: `MainLoop`, `timeout_source_new`, `timeout_source_new_seconds`, `idle_source_new`, and `io_add_watch`

*Note*: Please remember to provide a reference or some test results with your answer.